# How send objects from my service to my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm making a web site with WCF and a part of my team are responsable for the services and I'm responsable for the frontoffice. But now I have a question: how can I do to send to my views something given from the services wich use a proxy? I already have this in my controllers:

```
using (var client = Service.Proxy.Something)
        {
            var result = client.GetList(Guid.NewGuid());
        }
```

Comment: Need more information, what does `GetList()` return (I assume a list of something, but what)? Are you asking what your `if(result.)` line should be?

Comment: Sorry, forget the if(result.). How can I use this result to send the objects to my view? The GetList() return something from the service, don't matter now what that is.

Comment: Ok, simply I did 

            `try
            {
                using (var client = Service.Proxy.Something)
                {
                    var result = client.GetList(Guid.NewGuid());
                    return View(result.Result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            
            return View();`

and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view's model binding type matches what is passed back from the `GetList()` call then you can just do this:

Controller code:

```
return View(result);
```

View code:

```
@model List<YourObject>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <div>@item.Name</div>
}
```

Note: If your return type is not `List<YourObject>` then you will need to write some mapping code in your controller or a helper class/method to get the list of types returned from the service to match what your view expects.